# Is there a way to move window off top edge of display?

Tags: macos, mojave

I was wondering, since macOS is letting us move the window up top only until the title bar hits the top edge - is there a way to move a window past it?

There are some apps like VLC with which this could be possible (I can drag the video by clicking and holding anywhere in the picture and not by title bar).

Currently running macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to move an app window past the top edge of screen in macOS (irrespective of whether Menu bar is set to auto-hide or not).

Some app windows (such as FaceTime, QuickTime Player, VLC etc.) can be dragged by clicking and holding the window anywhere, not just the title bar. However, attempting to drag past the top edge may lead macOS to invoke Mission Control.

[image]